# Moodle with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, moodle, moodle-api

Currently, I am working on a rails application which requires the user to be registered automatically in the moodle. I searched for it and found these gems,

1. moodle-api: https://github.com/getsmarter/moodle-api
2. moodle_rb: https://github.com/jobready/moodle-rb/
3. moodle: https://github.com/robertboloc/moodle

But, nothing seems to work for me. I even searched on youtube but found nothing with the rails.

However, using the `moodle_rb` gem I was able to create an object which returned me the sites info using the `sites_info` function. Other than that I am unable to use any of the web services of the moodle. I have created an external service and added some functions like `auth_email_get_signup_settings` and `auth_email_signup_user` which accepts none parameters.

May anyone guides me through this? or even a minor help would also be great.

I am using a token to create the object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide code examples that you tried and that didn't work? It's hard to know the right direction to point you in without knowing what you've done.

Comment: Hi, Please check my comment on the answer given by calebkm. Thanks for giving your time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how you tried to configure your gems? For example, according to the docs the `moddle-api` gem requires a configuration like:

```rb
 Moodle::Api.configure do|c|
  c.host = 'http://my_moodle_instance.com'
  c.token = 'mytoken'
end
```

If you did configure the gem like the above, can you show some of the code that you tried to call once the gem was installed and configured?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. The code that you provided did not work for me. However, After hours of searching and trial and error, I found out that the main issue was in my moodle setting. The token needs to add some user to be added to it and also enable them to let them use the token and access the functions added to the external service. I appreciate you for giving your precious time after my query. Honestly, I was not able to find that option now.  The whole moodle site admin interface is so clumsy. :(